# rundeck service fails to start Could not create the Java Virtual Machine

Tags: rundeck

My Rundeck instance out of nowhere could not display the execution log and SCM looked weird, therefore I decided to reboot VM. After reboot Rundeck service fails to start.

Service log shows this

```
[2022-10-19T12:56:07,639] WARN  config.NavigableMap - Accessing config key '[errorpage]' through dot notation is deprecated, and it will be removed in a future release. Use 'config.getProperty(key, targetClass)' instead.
[2022-10-19T12:56:07,639] WARN  config.NavigableMap - Accessing config key '[errorpage, hidestacktrace]' through dot notation is deprecated, and it will be removed in a future release. Use 'config.getProperty(key, targetClass)' instead.
[2022-10-19T13:08:36,394] ERROR services.ExecutionUtilService - Execution failed: 91 in project Inventory: [Workflow result: , step failures: {1=Dispatch failed on 1 nodes: [qvc-ops02.ilabs.io: NonZeroResultCode: Result code was 1 + {dataContext=MultiDataContextImpl(map={ContextView(node:qvc-ops02.ilabs.io)=BaseDataContext{{exec={exitCode=0}}}, ContextView(step:1, node:qvc-ops02.ilabs.io)=BaseDataContext{{exec={exitCode=0}}}}, base=null)} ]}, Node failures: {qvc-ops02.ilabs.io=[NonZeroResultCode: Result code was 1 + {dataContext=MultiDataContextImpl(map={ContextView(node:qvc-ops02.ilabs.io)=BaseDataContext{{exec={exitCode=0}}}, ContextView(step:1, node:qvc-ops02.ilabs.io)=BaseDataContext{{exec={exitCode=0}}}}, base=null)} ]}, status: failed]
[2022-10-19T14:10:31,918] DEBUG authentication.GrailsUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to JaasAuthenticationToken [Principal=admin, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1], SessionId=node0agu3cv4a15qpk65mu7cydbed27], Granted Authorities=[Jaas Authority [admin,admin], Jaas Authority [build,build], Jaas Authority [architect,architect], Jaas Authority [user,user], Jaas Authority [deploy,deploy]]]
[2022-10-19T19:23:03,653] DEBUG authentication.GrailsUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to JaasAuthenticationToken [Principal=admin, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1], SessionId=node04547cljp2grjbeh3mvzrnd8d29], Granted Authorities=[Jaas Authority [admin,admin], Jaas Authority [build,build], Jaas Authority [architect,architect], Jaas Authority [user,user], Jaas Authority [deploy,deploy]]]
[2022-10-19T19:25:28,072] ERROR plugins.RundeckPluginRegistry - Plugin git-export for service: ScmExport was not found
[2022-10-19T19:25:28,072] WARN  services.PluginService - ScmExport not found: git-export
[2022-10-19T19:25:28,073] ERROR plugins.RundeckPluginRegistry - Plugin git-import for service: ScmImport was not found
[2022-10-19T19:25:28,073] WARN  services.PluginService - ScmImport not found: git-import
[2022-10-19T19:25:38,256] ERROR plugins.RundeckPluginRegistry - Plugin git-export for service: ScmExport was not found
[2022-10-19T19:25:38,256] WARN  services.PluginService - ScmExport not found: git-export
[2022-10-19T19:25:38,256] ERROR plugins.RundeckPluginRegistry - Plugin git-import for service: ScmImport was not found
[2022-10-19T19:25:38,256] WARN  services.PluginService - ScmImport not found: git-import

Session terminated, killing shell...[2022-10-19T19:29:21,521] INFO  rundeckapp.BootStrap - Rundeck Shutdown detected
 ...killed.
Unrecognized option: --skipinstall
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Unrecognized option: --skipinstall
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Comment: More context is needed, Which Rundeck version are you using? Which Java version? Operating system? Install method? How do you try to launch Rundeck?

Comment: @MegaDrive68k Rundeck ver 4.6.1 runs on RHEL8.6, Java 11, install method RPM from repo. This instance was working fine just yesterday. Out of nowhere, upon running the job, it gave me a error "unable to display log", at the same time SMC plugin showed all my jobs as modified. After VM reboot rundeck did not come up. I did not ran any update of any kind.

Comment: It seems to be a filesystem integrity problem (similar to this: https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/4210). Is that instance an upgraded instance? Could you check the presence of WAR file like this? https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/4210#issuecomment-438861189

Comment: @MegaDrive68k Thank you! You were correct - the war file simply was gone from the bootstrap folder. Once I placed one back Rundeck is up and running.

Comment: Great! I added the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

That error happens when the main rundeck war file isn't present on the bootstrap directory (`/var/rundeck/bootstrap/` path) probably deleted. Take a look a [this](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/4210#issuecomment-438861189).